# form java regex to php regex

Tags: java, php, regex

I have a regular expression in Java:  `[^a-zA-Z0-9.-_]`

How to form this regular expression from `java` to `php`?

Comment: For the most part, you can use the *same* syntax across regex implementations in *many* languages.  In this (albeit simple) case, the syntax for PHP and Java should be identical.  Q: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

In php (PCRE) this regular expression looks like

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9.-_]
```

<sub>*Yep, it's exactly the same*</sub>

Comment: Can you state the obvious pls? :)

Answer (score 0):

it is the same for this particular regex.

But you can make shorter with:

```
[^\w.-]
```

and don't forget that the - character must be placed at the last position in a character class

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r: By default shorthand character classes (`\w`, `\d`, `\s`) contains only ASCII characters and have nothing to do with locales. See http://pcre.org

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same *but* you might need to put delimiters around it, e.g. parenthesis:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9._-])
```

See the little difference moving the minus to the end. That is because `[.-_]` matches `./0...9:;<=>?@A...Z[\]^_`. I guess you're not looking for the negation of this as you had already 0-9 and A-Z covered.

Comment: You should do yourself a favor and use other character (e.g. `~`, `#`) as delimiter, so that you don't confuse yourself (and others) of whether `()` is the delimiter or the capturing group.